# Implementing middleware before resolving and returning result

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I want to check user auth before querying. Initially, I tried implementing a custom directive extending FieldMiddleware. But realized, this is checking the **field** of the in the returned model in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809972/middleware-in-laravel-lighthouse-v5-10) .

Anyway, is there a way to check run a code snippet before the resolver returns the results?
Any direction or help is much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct. Using FieldMiddleware is the way to go to run additional code before resolving a Query in my case.

If you're seeking an implementation, the one in the docs is good enough. [Link here](https://lighthouse-php.com/4/custom-directives/field-directives.html#fieldmiddleware).